# Modify a record built as erased type with FSharp.Data JsonProvider

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I have a type created with JsonProvider:

```
type ThisRecord = JsonProvider<"ThisRecord.json">
```

It is a quite deep and complex one, but to simplify let's say it has two properties:

```
{
    Prop1 = "prop1"
    Prop2 = 2
}
```

For test purposes, I want to create easily new samples from a given one modifying just one or two properties. With normal records it would be:

```
let modified = {sample with Prop2 = -3}
```

This seems not to be possible with the erased types created with JsonProvider.

Does it exist any simpler way to build modified versions of a given provided type or do I have to create new *.json files for each test case?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any simpler way. In my case, I had to resort to the following:

1. Explicitly define my own Record types
2. Copy the data from the JsonProvider's erased type into my own type
3. Use my types throughout my code.

I'm not saying this is a desirable solution. But, I think it is what we are left with. Defining your own "business objects" separate from the JsonProvider's auto-generated erased types solves both the problem you mention and another problem you do not mention: The erased types do not work with reflection-based APIs.